# PHP - Has anyway to encrypt/decrpyt hash in PHP?

Tags: php, encryption, hash, hashcode

I'm interested to encrypt/decrpyt hash in PHP.

But as I know hash can be encoding only with md5, sha1, sha256.

However, is it possible to make encrypt/decrpyt in PHP by another hash like ripemd160, haval256,5 or ripemd256?

Thank

Comment: *"I'm interested to encrypt/decrpyt hash in PHP."* - I almost popped this in an answer below: A: you can't. Hashes are "one way".

Comment: PHP offers a suite of encryption functions. See http://php.net/manual/en/ref.openssl.php

Comment: *"However, is it possible to make encrypt/decrpyt in PHP by another hash like ripemd160, haval256,5 or ripemd256?"* http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php  Again: no, they're all "one way", any way you slice it or dice it.

Comment: A "hash" is a one-way ticket. It's not ment to be decrypted - thats the whole point. You want to *encrypt* instead, which can be decrypted. And I'm not sure for what purpose, but most likely `md5()`, `sha1()` are outdated and not worth your time.

Comment: @Fredd-i- In the real world, most short strings can be reversed by dictionaries. Try to reverse this md5 with google search: 570a90bfbf8c7eab5dc5d4e26832d5b1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hashing algorithms are not encryption algorithms. Hashing algorithms have the following principles:

- Specific input produces always the same output
- The input cannot be resolved based on the output
- Any change to input will produce different output

Technically the last one is not true, because you have limited amount of possible outputs but basically unlimited amount of possible inputs. Therefore there will be other inputs that produces the same output, but for strong hashing algorithms finding those collisions takes VERY long time as @delboy1978uk explained.

MD5 is an example of a weak hashing algorithm that you should not use for secure hashes. Collision attacks against MD5 are cheap. On the other hand hashing algorithms in SHA2 family can be considered secure (take SHA256 for example).

Encryption algorithms require a key or multiple keys to allow you to do decryption on the cipher text.

The short answer to your questions is no.

Comment: Note that a single bit of difference in the input results in approximately 50% of the output bits to change.

Answer (score 2):

Hashes are one way algorithms.The only way to crack them is by brute force.

As an example, Bitcoin uses SHA-256 hashes for the receiving addresses. You can brute force the first couple of letters/digits quite quickly, but even just cracking the first 6 will take over a day. 7 will take a week, 8 could be months! Cracking an entire bitcoin address would take years upon years!

So I'm afraid what you are asking can't be done.

Comment: Hashes are not encryption algorithms but products of hashing algorithms. Hashing algorithms are not encryption algorithms either.

Comment: My point is the algorithm is one way, and that's what he needs to realise.

Comment: the word encryption has been removed.

Comment: now "crack" is in its place